# this.emit(':ask') not working

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have created one intent SampleIntent on amazon skill which prompts the user to enter the city name. Once entered, I have to save that city name, and then again it will prompt/ask user "Do you want to continue ?" If the user enters yes, it will again prompt for the city name, and exit if the user enters no.

For this I have created two slots in Sample Intent. My utterance are {slotA} and {slotB}. When I access SampleIntent it prompts for ener City name but on console I am getting undefined. It is also never reaching the prompt for continuing or not.

Below is my sample model:

```
{
            "name": "SampleIntent",
            "slots": [
                {
                    "name": "cityName",
                    "type": "cityName"
                },
                {
                    "name": "confirmForMore",
                    "type": "confirmForMore"
                }
            ],
            "samples": [
                "{fName} ",
                "{confirmForMore}",
                "CityName"
            ]
        }
```

Code in node.js is below

```
this.emit(':ask', 'Please provide City Name');
cityName = intent.slots.cityName.value;
console.log('cityName :' + cityName );

this.emit(':ask', 'Do u like details for other City?');
confirmForMore = intent.slots.confirmForMore.value;
console.log("confirmForMore : "+confirmForMore);
```

Line no 4 to 6 never executes and each time asking for city name. If I enter city name I am not able to see cityName in console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me for this query??

Comment: Yes because, Alexa doesn't hold the execution of your lambda for slot information. What you need to do is to check if the slot information is already filled or not. If already filled ask for next slot information.

Comment: Or else, if you need this information every time user invokes the intent, in that case just check mark the required checkbox in your Alexa Skill Builder and provide some sample utterances.

Answer (score 0):

See this is the way how your **Alexa and Lambda function works**.

1. First you provide some utterance to your lambda function : *"Which CITY do you live in?"*
2. Then Alexa creates a **JSON input** for your lambda function based on the input you provide in last step and the intent invoked and sends it to lambda function.
3. Lambda Function returns some **JSON output** which is suitable for Alexa and contains variables like `speechOutput`, etc and sends it back to Alexa.
4. Now Alexa speaks the output returned by the lambda function.

What is happening in your skill is, when you ask for a slot information `cityName`, it works fine and asks for the slot information and probably gets you the right info too. But now what happens is User provides some utterance like *"YES"* or *"NO"* in your case, and your lambda function executes from the top. Which results in execution of this block again.

```
this.emit(':ask', 'Please provide City Name');
cityName = intent.slots.cityName.value;
console.log('cityName :' + cityName );
```

To avoid such thing what you can do is something like this :

```
if (cityName in intent.slots && intent.slots.cityName.value <= 0){
    this.emit(':ask', 'Please provide City Name');
    cityName = intent.slots.cityName.value;
    console.log('cityName :' + cityName );
}
else {
    this.emit(':ask', 'Do u like details for other City?');
    confirmForMore = intent.slots.confirmForMore.value;
    console.log("confirmForMore : "+confirmForMore);
}
```